# Links inside comments replacing current page rather than taking me to new tab url

Tags: feature-request, bug

It appears, adding `comment` with `link` to post at `askubuntu.com` loading new `url` to current page rather than new tab.
How about adding a **target="_blank"** with every `link` so I dont lose my current conversion and open a new `askubuntu` page and start conversation again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always return to where you were with the back button of your browser. Or (depending on the browser) using one of the keyboard modifiers (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.) to open it in a new tab.

Personally, I prefer that to each click *automatically* opening a new tab. That gets messy if you do it too often.

Comment: What browser uses Alt+Click to open in a new tab? I haven't seen that one.